# !slist command in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

I'm on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit. In WinDBG, I open an executable and then enter the command

```
!slist $teb _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD 0
```

but here's what I get:

```
SLIST HEADER:
   +0x000 Header8.Sequence          : fd
   +0x000 Header8.Depth            : d000
   +0x008 Region             : 0

SLIST CONTENTS:
00000000001d0110
   +0x000 Next             : ???? 
   +0x008 Handler          : ???? 
Can't read memory at 00000000001d0110, error 0
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

edit: I'm trying to display the exception handler chain manually. If I enter

```
!exchain
```

everything works fine:

```
4 stack frames, scanning for handlers...
Frame 0x00: ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30 (00000000`7787cb70)
  ehandler ntdll!_C_specific_handler (00000000`777e852c)
Frame 0x01: ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x17c7 (00000000`77832bed)
  ehandler ntdll!_GSHandlerCheck (00000000`777e9840)
Frame 0x02: ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x28ff0 (00000000`77811937)
  ehandler ntdll!_C_specific_handler (00000000`777e852c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens when one uses the 64-bit version of WinDBG to debug 32-bit executables. It's better to install both versions of WinDBG and use the 32-bit version for debugging 32-bit apps.